# How can I add other DbSet<xxx> in UsersContext class when I user InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a `asp.net mvc4` Internet Application.

There was a UsersContext class in Models folder. I tried to add a POCO in this class.

```
[Table("Book")]
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
}
```

And then I added a DbSet in UsersContext.

When I run the application using the default connection string.

> Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial
>   Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication2-20161129121332;Integrated
>   Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication2-20161129121332.mdf

The 6 tables were created.
But if I change the connection string to `Server=.; DataBase=demo; User ID=abc; Pwd=123456`. All tables were created but the Book table.

I want to know why this happened, and how can I do to make the Book table be created?